# Collect Child record fields into a CSV field on a parent

Tags: apex, trigger, csv

Because reporting on Opportunities with Team Members add rows for each member, I'd like to collect Opportunity Team Members into a single field and display them on the Opportunity Object  - 
for visibility, reporting, etc.

I will update via a Trigger on the OpportunityTeamMember :

```
trigger OppTeamCollector2 on OpportunityTeamMember (after update, after insert, after delete) {


if((Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) && Trigger.isAfter){

Set<Id> OppIds = new Set<Id>();

// find the ids of all accounts that were affected
       for (OpportunityTeamMember ar : [select Id, OpportunityId from OpportunityTeamMember 
      where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()])
      OppIds.add(ar.OpportunityId);


 OpportunityTeamTriggerHandler.ProcessOppTeamAsync(OppIds);

}
}
```

Here is my handler class - compiles, throws now errors, but doesn't write to the field:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityTeamTriggerHandler {

  @future 
  public static void ProcessOppTeamAsync(Set<ID> OppIds){

    // holds a map of the Opp id and comma separated Users to build
    Map<Id, String> OppMap = new Map<Id, String>();

  // get ALL of the Teams for all affected Opps so we can build
    List<OpportunityTeamMember> OppTeamMembers = [select id, UserID, OpportunityId, User.name 
      from OpportunityTeamMember 
      where OpportunityId IN :OppIds order by UserID];

 for (OpportunityTeamMember ar : OppTeamMembers) {
      if (!OppMap.containsKey(ar.OpportunityId)) {

        OppMap.put(ar.OpportunityId,ar.User.Name);
      } else {

        OppMap.put(ar.OpportunityId,OppMap.get(ar.OpportunityId) + 
          ', ' + ar.User.Name);
      }
    } 

 // get the Opps that were affected
    List<Opportunity> OpportunitiesUP = [select id from Opportunity where Id IN :OppIds];   


     // add the comma separated list of Teams


       for (Opportunity OP : OpportunitiesUP)
          OP.Team__c = OppMap.get(OP.id);

update OpportunitiesUP;
      }

    }
```

Can someone find my error? Thanks!

Comment: The next level of utility would be to only collect unique values, I don't need that for this project but can think of another place I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually update your Opportunities. You should add some error handling so that you either send out an email or store a logging object of some sort because in a `@future` method errors will not block your DML.

So somewhere in your code, you need some form of:

```
try
{
    update opportunities;
}
catch (DMLException dmx)
{
    // do stuff
    // store a log object?
    // send an error email?
}
```

You should probably build out a library for this sort of error handling if you don't already have one.

I would also recommend using `Map<Id, Set<String>>` and then doing a `String.join` on your results at the end, though that has nothing to do with why you are not seeing updates.

Comment: Thanks, simple error I lost the update when editing. Thanks

Comment: Approve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Adrian has it pegged so this is more about coding simplification for the future method:

```
@future 
public static void ProcessOppTeamAsync(Set<ID> oIdSet){
 List<Opportunity> oUpdList = new List<Opportunity> ();
 for (Opportunity o : [select id, (select id, user.name
                                   from OpportunityTeamMembers)
                        from Opportunity where id IN: oIdSet) {
   List<String> usernameList = new List<String>(); 
   for (OpportunityTeamMember otm: o.opportunityTeamMembers) 
      userNameList.add(otm.user.name);
   oUpdList.add(new Opportunity(id = o.id, team__c = String.join(usernameList,','));
 }

 Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(oUpdList,false);  // allow for partial successes
 for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList)
   if (!sr.isSuccess()) 
      // do something like notify sysad or store in log
}
```

Note the use of the relationship query to get all of the OTM underneath the relevant opportunities. This avoids the maps which in this use case are not needed.

Note also the partial success option as this is future so try and get as many records to save as possible in batch scenario.

*Code just typed in so maybe trivial compile error that you can correct*

Finally - keep an eye on the free package [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) which has planned enhancements to do this kind of text-based concatenation rollups all via point-and-click

Comment: Thanks - and I will keep an eye on that package - I use it and would love to use for something like this.